# Report SSRS - Display percentage and value on a chart

Tags: reporting-services, percentage, ssrs-2008-r2

Is that possible to display value and percentage in a datalabel for a chart in SSRS ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is posible.
In Series Label Properties Set Label Data to for example : `#PERCENT -  #VALY` it will be display in this format "27 % - 78"